Using name of attribute table in clipping raster to mask layer
I'm trying to clip a .tif file to a shapefile. This shapefile contains 800 different polygons with all different names stated in the attribute table (BasinIDs).
When I clip the .tif to the polygon I get an output of all the different polygons filled with the information of the .tif. The names of the polygons are like 1,2,3,4,5.... etc. Now I want to give them the name they had before in the attribute table so I know which polygon is which.
Does someone know how to do this?
Using: QGIS version 3.34.7

Do you want to create one raster file for each of the 800 polygons, named by the polygon attribute?

Try this:
Rasterize the polygon layer - menu Raster>Conversion>Rasterize Vector to Raster.
Then combine the rasterized polygon layer and your clipped tif into a multiband raster using menu item Raster>Miscellaneous>Merge.
Here is some output of the process:

This image shows the results of the identify tool displaying the polygon identifier and the cell value for the current pixel.

Not sure of a way that you can have a text identifier in a raster.  You could display the rasterized layer using a palleted/unique values symbology and edit the labels so that the names are visible in the legend.

